# Trouble pushing android studio project to GitHub

Tags: android, git, github

I've literally spent days trying to figure out whats going on, but no matter what project I try to push/share to GitHub when I select the 'share project on GitHub' button under VCS --> Import into version control --> Share project on GitHub this dialog box will pop up:

[image]

So like I said, this occurred in one project so I closed and attempted to do the same from a newer project, however I keep getting the same result. The project that it keeps referring to was built in Xcode for the iPhone not within Android Studio. Why does this keep happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you actually _trying_ to do? Pushing a new project to Github or overwriting a project previously written or simply pushing changes to an already existing project?

Comment: I'm trying to 'share it to GitHub' for the first-time with this specific project, but the other projects keep pointing to this specific location as well.

Comment: So you're trying to create a new repo on Github using this project code as the initial commit? If so, then you need to make sure that the repo you're pushing has a unique name (i.e. make sure there isn't already a repo on Github with the same name).